# Setting default or a combobox with Xaml (despite Binding)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I want to Bind the selectedItem of an RadCombobox to an Observable Collection in the DataContext. This works perfectly fine. 
But now I want to set the default value for the combobox, this also works if I set the Variable in the Data Context. But It would be better in my opinion to set the deault within the Xaml. This should be possible with `SelectedIndex="0"` unfortunatly ths doesnt work anymore (no default shown) since the binding is active.

Is there an option to set deault value or the combobox while there is a binding for the SelectedItem?

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="radComboBox" 
                             ItemsSource="{Binding xyList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" SelectedItem="{Binding Selectedxy}" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Height="25" Grid.Row="1">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

.

```
public string Selectedxy  {get;set; }

        public void FillxyDropdown()
        {
           xyList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> Line in model.ReadxyList())
            {
                xyList.Add(Line.Key);
            }

            //Sets the default value but isnt the desired way.
            Selectedxy = "XY3.31";
        }
```

Comment: I always set the default values in the View Model, that's what it is for

Comment: Selectedxy  should be notified whenever it is changed. This is missing in your case. Check out [how-to-implement-property-change-notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [The One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62153833/setting-default-or-a-combobox-with-xaml-despite-binding#comment109925564_62153833) comment. You definitely should specify the default values in the View Model.

If you still want to do this in the XAML, you can set the binding mode of the `SelectedItem` property to `OneWayToSource`. In this case, `Selectedxy` will be updated when `SelectedItem` changes, but not the other way around.

```xml
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="radComboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding xyList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="1" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Selectedxy, Mode=OneWayToSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Height="25" Grid.Row="1">
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks you two, I guess I have to accept it then. Just seemd more logical to me to set "show default or dont show default" with the Xaml element and not "afterwards". But well ^^